# How to update Angular cli version for existing application?

Tags: angular

I am running my angular 2 application using npm start, here ng serve, ng build commanda are not working, i try to build this application it shows an  error message[ng build error messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2MXB.jpg)

Comment: The error message suggest that you can run `ng build` command only in folder containing Angular project. So first `cd` to that folder and then issue build command

Answer (score 1):

If u run this command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

it will automatically download the latest version of angular
@ before angular  is mainly used to get the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Go to your application's package.json file where you can find devDependencies and you will see your application cli version. you can change the version there and you can use npm install again.

Comment: thank you , prsesnt i 1.0.0-beta.28.3 this version and tried npm install but i behaves same...

Comment: can i see your package.json

Answer (score -1):

run `ng build` in  project root directory where package.json file is located